# UISwipeGestureRecognizer to override all others?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have an pretty standard application that uses gesture recognizers in various places. I’m trying to add an above-all `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` with three fingers which can be performed anywhere in the app, similar to the Apple four-fingered ones. This is working fine in some views, but if there’s another swipe recognizer beneath it, it’ll trigger that one instead of the new one.

I’d like this new three-finger swipe to be given priority at all times – I’ve added it to my root view controller’s `view`, but it still seems to bleed through at times.

Is there an easier way to do this than going through and requiring all other recognizers to fail?

Comment: You don't have to "go through". Implement the delegate methods and all the other gesture recognizers will come to you for permission! Your implementation can be quite short and simple; the "looping" is done by the runtime for you.

Comment: That seems to be working, but it’s also still triggering the recogniser beneath. I need it to cancel that one. I’ve implemented `shouldReceiveTouch` and `shouldRecognizeSimultaneously` and just returned `YES` in both cases. What else do I need to do to override the lower recognizer?

Comment: The delegate methods you want are called `gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:` and `estureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:` They will be called for all pairs, i.e. your recognizer and every other recognizer that might conflict. "Fail" means "go first", "get priority over the other".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` method to filter through unneeded gestures.
[Apple doc.](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/requireGestureRecognizerToFail%3a)

Comment: I know, I asked if there was an easier way ;)